# ADO.NET - Connect to SQL Server with Windows Login with login and password supplied by the application

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, ado.net, impersonation

This is SQL Server 2008 R2, .NET 4.0.

In my SQL Server there is a user created with "Windows Authentication". The user exists in a Active Directory domain.

I want to make a .NET application connect to the SQL Server as this user. Inside the application, I know the user's domain, login and password, and the application has network access to the AD server.

How can I accomplish this?

I know that ASP.NET has it's AD provider and impersonation. But what I'm looking for is a really generic solution, one that should work on a plain console application. Something that I could use on console app, windows forms, asp.net, or a common business class library.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: To better clarify: I need to use "Integrated Security=true" on the SQL connection string. But I need to impersonate a certain AD user before attempting to connect to the SQL Server. The user actually running my application is NOT the SQL AD user. But inside the application I will know the AD user's credentials, so I should be able to impersonate it before attempting to connect to the SQL, the question is: how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it using this class:

https://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/

You must impersonate using LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9 if the computer does not belong to the domain.

Once impersonated, then connect to SQL using "Integrated Security=true" on the SQL Connection String.

```
SqlConnection conn;
using (new Impersonator("myUserName", "myDomain", "myPassword", LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT))
{
    conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=databaseIp;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=true;");
    conn.Open();
}
//(...) use the connection at your will.
//Even after the impersonation context ended, the connection remains usable.
```

Comment: If the behaviour described in the "ALERT" definitely true?

I am trying to reproduce it by creating new connections with same querystring but executed under different impersonated users, and each runs under the correct impersonated user.

Would you be ale to post or a code snippet that demonstrate it?

Comment: Hi, I don't have the environment anymore to properly write code and test it. But in the above code snippet, after the using block, you could do conn.Close(); and if you're sure that you have no other connections in your pool, if you do conn.Open(); you will get that same first connection made with that user name, even outside of the using block.  Even if you create another SqlConnection object with exactly the same connection string you should get the same first connection (provided you closed it - hence returned it to the pool).

Comment: Thanks for the replies, however in my tests it does not behave that way.

One thing I noticed is that in the code snipped above the connection is defined and used *outside* the using block for the impersonation.

In my test the connection is created and disposed of inside the block:

private void test(credentials)
{
  using(impersonation(credentials))
  {
    using(new connection("trusted"))
    {
        open connection, execute SQL, close connection
    }
  }
}

Calling test() multiple times with different credentials behaves correctly.

Comment: I guess you are right, this article states "Connections are pooled according to the connection string plus the user identity." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/8xx3tyca(v=vs.100)

Comment: It's been 5 years, I can't remember exactly how I came to that conclusion. I think I have tested it and saw it happening, but I'm not sure anymore. And I can't verify it again, I no longer work in the company that I used to back then and I don't have access to a proper environment to test it. Since you say you tested it, and Microsoft docs say they use the identity as part of the connection pool key, I will remove that alert from my answer.